# "Pixels out of bounds" error in IRAF

Tags: linux, fits

I am trying to do a PSF fitting on a fits image using SNOOPY (a point spread function fitter) and IRAF. I can open this image fine using imexam but when I select a point (a star or whatever) I get an error:

```
Warning: Pixels out of bounds
```

It seems that what I am seeing and what IRAF is seeing (behind the scenes) are not the same. As if there is some kind of a co-ordinate off-shift or something.

How would one go about fixing this ?

[Scientific Linux 6, 16bit , IRAF v2.16]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using DS9 v7.2 then the problem is a bug in the DS9 cursor read causing the offset.  The only workaround is to use an earlier version of DS9 or a more recent beta.

Comment: Worked perfectly my friend . I was in fact using v7.2 . There is a Beta version v7.3b5 . http://ds9.si.edu/site/Beta.html Not sure what other differences there are between v7.2 and v7.3b5 but this problem is certainly solved . Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am also getting the "Warning Pixels out of bounds" error in imexamine for parts of images in the 8th frame only of an 8 frame FITS image, using DS9 7.3.2 with pyraf.  The 7.3 beta is no longer available.

A workaround is to load the subimage into ds9 using iraf, rather than loading it directly in ds9.